# Use WP Shortcode as an attribute in another Shortcode

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to use the Advanced Custom Fields plugin shortcode as a attribute in another shortcode.

The company my theme was made by is not offering custom support at this time.

The original shortcode is made list this

```
public function plan( $atts, $content )
    {
        $html = array();

        extract( shortcode_atts( array(
            'price'     => '',
            'price_info'    => '',
            'type'  => '',
            'delay'     => '',
            'class'     => '',
        ), $atts ) ); 

        $html[] = '<div class="' . ( $class ) . '">';
        $html[] =   '<div class="plan has-animation" data-delay="' . ( (int)$delay ) . '">';
        $html[] =       '<div class="plan-container">';
        $html[] =           '<ins class="plan-price">' .( $price ) . '</ins>';
        $html[] =           '<span class="price-info">' . ( $price_info ) . '</span>';
        $html[] =           '<h2 class="second_color">' . ( $type ) . '</h2>';

        $html[] =           do_shortcode( $content );

        $html[] =       '</div>';
        $html[] =   '</div>';
        $html[] = '</div>';

        return implode("\n", $html); 
    }
```

And when i call the shortcode `[pt_plan price="$12.99" price_info="per month" type="Standard" delay="400" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4"]` I want to make the price attribute allow a shortcode as a value to take advantage of Advanced Custom Fields.

However, if I place `[acf field='session_price_1']` as the attribute value, like this, `[pt_plan price="[acf field='session_price_1']" price_info="per month" type="Standard" delay="400" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4"]` it comes out as if that was a string and breaks the original pt_plan shortcode.

Could someone point me in the right direction? I thought it would be to add `do_shortcode()` to the $price variable in the plan shortcode, but it did not work.

Hope all this makes sense and thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually got it to work.
Because the way shortcodes work in WP, the ending ] of the nested shortcode was closing off the original shortcode, screwing everything up.
To get around this, I did the following:

```
$html[] = '<div class="plan-price">'.do_shortcode('['.$price.']').'</div>';
```

and

```
[pt_plan price="acf field='session_price_1'" price_info="per month" type="Standard" delay="400" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4"]
```

and that worked great!

Basically I just typed the text of the shortcode and ' instead of " into the attribute, concatenated the [ and ] in when it prints the attribute value into the , and used `do_shortcode()` to run the shortcode.